# How to post files using JSoup?

Tags: java, post, file-upload, jsoup

I`m using the following code post values using JSoup:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www......com/....php")
                    .data("user","user","password","12345","email","info@tutorialswindow.com")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute()
                    .parse();
```

And now I want to submit a  file, too. Like a form with a file field. 
Is this possible ? If is than how ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is only supported since Jsoup 1.8.2 (Apr 13, 2015)
via the new [`data(String, String, InputStream)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#data-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-) method.

```
String url = "http://www......com/....php";
File file = new File("/path/to/file.ext");

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .data("user", "user")
    .data("password", "12345")
    .data("email", "info@tutorialswindow.com")
    .data("file", file.getName(), new FileInputStream(file))
    .post();
// ...
```

In older versions, sending `multipart/form-data` requests is not supported. Your best bet is using a fullworthy HTTP client for this, such as [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). You can ultimately get the HTTP client response as `String` so that you can feed it to [`Jsoup#parse()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

```
String url = "http://www......com/....php";
File file = new File("/path/to/file.ext");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("user", new StringBody("user"));
entity.addPart("password", new StringBody("12345"));
entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("info@tutorialswindow.com"));
entity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName()));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(entity);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
String html = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, url);
// ...
```

Comment: Since JSoup 1.12.1 sending multipart/form-data requests is even possible without having files involved in the form data. see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100270/363573

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer works and was correct at the time of writing, but since then JSoup has evolved and [since version 1.8.2 it is possible to send files as part of multipart forms](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#data-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-):

```
File file1 = new File("/path/to/file");
FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream(file1);

Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www......com/....php")
    .data("user","user","password","12345","email","info@tutorialswindow.com")            
    .data("file1", "filename", fs1)
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();
```

Comment: JSoup 1.12.1 introduced full support for multipart forms as long as the content type header is set. see details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100270/363573

Answer (score 1):

This post led me to the right path but I had to tweak the posted answers to make my use case work. Here's my code:

```
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileToSend);
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl + authUrl)
                .data("username",username)
                .data("password",password);
        Document document = conn.post();

        System.out.println("Login successfully! Session Cookie: " + conn.response().cookies());


        System.out.println("Attempting to upload file...");
        document = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl + uploadUrl)
                .data("file",fileToSend.getName(),fs)
                .cookies(conn.response().cookies())
                .post();
```

The basic difference is that I first login to the site, retain the cookie from the response (`conn`) and then use it for the subsequent upload of the file.

Hope it helps guys.