# JSOUP + multipart/form-data response

Tags: java, post, jsoup, multipartform-data

In general, I need to send data to a site in the form of response multipart / form-data by JSOUP

As an example, take a simple form that sgeniriruet your query.

<form action=«[localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000)» method=«post» enctype=«multipart/form-data»
<input type=«text» name=«text» value=«text default»
<input type=«file» name=«file1»
<input type=«file» name=«file2»
Submit</button
</form

Post Response by browser:

```
>Request Headers Provisional headers are shown Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryjtkXVNw9YVG1H2P9 Origin:null
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106
Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:8DCCE949-56FA-4AB0-81B7-DA2BC7960E5C
 
->Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryjtkXVNw9YVG1H2P9 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=«text»

text default
------WebKitFormBoundaryjtkXVNw9YVG1H2P9 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=«file1»; filename="" Content-Type:
application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundaryjtkXVNw9YVG1H2P9 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=«file2»; filename="" Content-Type:
application/octet-stream

------WebKitFormBoundaryjtkXVNw9YVG1H2P9--
```

I tried to create a similar request, but has not found the right way, so that the server received the request.

My code:

```
Map<String, String> responseMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
    String key1 = "------WebKitFormBoundary9A3GpeDAwfa0TBDK\r\n" +
         "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text\"\r\n\r\n";
    String value1 = "text default";
    headersMap.put(key1, value1);

    String key2 = "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary9A3GpeDAwfa0TBDK\r\n" +
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"doc_sma_ref_file\"; filename=\"\"" +
        "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    String value2 = "";
    headersMap.put(key2, value2);

    String key3 = "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary9A3GpeDAwfa0TBDK\r\n" +
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"doc_val_ref_file\"; filename=\"\"" +
        "\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    String value3 = "";
    headersMap.put(key3, value3);
    
    String key4 = "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary9A3GpeDAwfa0TBDK--";
    String value4 = "";
    headersMap.put(key4, value4);

    Connection.Response resBGT = Jsoup.connect(URL)
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9A3GpeDAwfa0TBDK")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36")
        .followRedirects(true)
        .data(responseMap)
        .cookies(cookies)
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .timeout(15000)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();
```

Maybe someone has experience in this matter. If you please send the right path.
Perhaps there is an opportunity to see a request generated jsoup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post files using JSoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370771/how-to-post-files-using-jsoup)

Comment: Since version 1.8.2 JSOUP have a possibilty to send multipart/form-data. But I can not understand how to do it

Comment: @AlexBykov Nearly 3 years after your comment, Jsoup 1.12.1 introduced  (Dec 2018) a nice feature for handling form boundaries automatically. (see the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63100270/363573)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the third parameter of `Connection.data`:

```
File file1 = new File("C:/dir/file1.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:/dir/file2.txt");
FileInputStream fs1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
FileInputStream fs2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com")
        .data("text", "value")
        .data("file1", "filename", fs1)
        .data("file2", "filename", fs2)
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

//Handle your response...
```

Answer (score 1):

Before, JSoup 1.12.1, its was not possible to send form boundaries automatically unless files were involded in the form posting.

Since 1.12.1, Jsoup can generate form boundaries when the `Content-Type` header is set to `"multipart/form-data"`. It is no more necessary to add files in the form data for generating mime boundary automatically.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(echoUrl)
            .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .userAgent(browserUa)
            .data("uname", "Jsoup", "uname", "Jonathan", "百", "度一下")
            .post();
```

As you can see in the above code, no files are used, however JSoup will handle form boundary on the fly because the content type is `multipart/form-data`.

**Sources :**

- [Issue 788](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/788) it I can send request post multipart/form-data without attachment of the file
- [Commit 56ea479](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/56ea479e22fdcb360696c5a922d6b45d9445e06d) Allow multipart form submission by setting header; automatically add boundary.